# 308 permanent redirect with uploading PDF to REST API

Tags: c#, rest, httpwebrequest

I want to upload PDF to CrossEngage platform using HttpWebRequest or RestClient. As response I'm getting : 308 permanent redirect, but when i try this on POSTMAN all is fine (200 OK). What i'm not doing that POSTMAN is doing ?

```
//RestClient 

byte[] dataBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
string converted = Convert.ToBase64String(dataBytes);

var client = new RestClient(Url+Action);
client.FollowRedirects = true;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);            
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("x-xng-authtoken", AuthToken);
request.AddHeader("x-xng-apiversion", "2");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/pdf");
request.AddParameter("application/pdf", converted, ParameterType.RequestBody);            
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

return response.Content;

//HttpWebRequest

try
{
    byte[] dataBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url + Action);               
    //request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
    request.Headers.Add("X-XNG-ApiVersion", "2");
    request.Headers.Add("X-XNG-AuthToken", AuthToken);
    request.Method = method;
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 1;
    request.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    request.PreAuthenticate = true;
    request.ContentLength = 0;
    request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

    if (1 == 1)
    {
        request.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length;
        request.ContentType = contentType;

        using (Stream requestBody = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestBody.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
        }
    }
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
catch (WebException webex)
{
    string m = "";

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webex.Response)
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        throw new Exception(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

I expect 200 OK status code

Thanks in advance

UPDATE: I have found a solution so it might help someone. 
Simply you need to call location given in Location response header.
Hereby complete code :

try
            {
                byte[] dataBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);

```
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url + Action);               
            //request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
            request.Headers.Add("X-XNG-ApiVersion", "2");
            request.Headers.Add("X-XNG-AuthToken", AuthToken);
            request.Method = method;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;


            if (1 == 1)
            {
                request.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length;
                request.ContentType = contentType;

                using (Stream requestBody = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    requestBody.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
                }
            }
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                if ((int)response.StatusCode >= 300 && (int)response.StatusCode <= 399)
                {
                    var uriString = response.Headers["Location"];
                    var apiClient = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriString);
                    apiClient.ContentType = contentType;
                    apiClient.Method = method;
                    apiClient.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
                    apiClient.Accept = "*/*";
                    apiClient.Headers.Add("X-XNG-ApiVersion", "2");
                    apiClient.Headers.Add("X-XNG-AuthToken", AuthToken);

                    apiClient.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length;


                    using (Stream requestBody = apiClient.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        requestBody.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
                    }
                    var r = apiClient.GetResponse();
                }

                response.Close();
            }

            return "";
        }
        catch (WebException webex)
        {
            string m = "";

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webex.Response)
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                throw new Exception(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }

        }
```

Comment: are you receiving the `location` header in your 308 response?

Comment: Hi Pranjal - thanks for message but I have already solved this. Regards